# How to pass data to a miniplayerand show the currently playing song in a spotify clone app

Tags: flutter, widget, setstate, statefulwidget

Basically I want to display a miniplayer whenever a Gridtile is pressed and the details on it should match the tile which was pressed.

```
class SongJBI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<SongJBI> createState() => SongJBIState();
}

class SongJBIState extends State<SongJBI> {
  

  @override
  final List<SongModel> sjmodel = [
    SongModel(
      id: 1,
      name: 'rockstar(feat. 21 Savage)',
      artist: 'Post Malone',
      image: Image.asset('assets/rockstar.jpg'),
    ),
    SongModel(
      id: 2,
      name: 'My Ordinary Life',
      artist: 'The Living Tombstone',
      image: Image.asset('assets/mol.jpg'),
    ),
    SongModel(
      id: 3,
      name: 'House of Memories',
      artist: 'Panic! At the Disco',
      image: Image.asset('assets/ho.jpg'),
    ),
    SongModel(
      id: 4,
      name: 'After Dark',
      artist: 'Mr. Kitty',
      image: Image.asset('assets/ad.jpg'),
    ),
  ];

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
          children: sjmodel.map((smo) {
        final data = SongModel(
          id: smo.id,
          name: smo.name,
          artist: smo.artist,
          image: smo.image,
        );

        return GridTile(
            child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Song_Screen(recdata: data),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: smo.image,
                    width: 150,
                    height: 150,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      smo.name,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      smo.artist,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
      }).toList()),
    );
  }
}
```

The data is originally shown on a song screen but I want the miniplayer to change its data according to tap so that when the song screen is minimized a miniplayer is rendered with the details of the song gridtile which was pressed.

This is the code for the Song Screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone/Models/song_model.dart';
import 'package:spotify_clone/Widgets/song_recommend.dart';

class Song_Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  final SongModel recdata;
  Song_Screen({required this.recdata});
  @override
  double _sliderValue = 0;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          leading: IconButton(
            splashRadius: 20,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
              size: 35,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              splashRadius: 20,
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.more_vert,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 300,
                  height: 300,
                  child: recdata.image,
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    recdata.name,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    recdata.artist,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade400, fontSize: 16),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  SliderTheme(
                    data: const SliderThemeData(
                        trackHeight: 2,
                        thumbShape:
                            RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 5),
                        overlayShape:
                            RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 0)),
                    child: Slider(
                      thumbColor: Colors.white,
                      inactiveColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
                      value: _sliderValue,
                      onChanged: ((value) {}),
                      activeColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '0:01',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey.shade300),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '3:00',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey.shade300),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    splashRadius: 20,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.favorite_border,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    splashRadius: 20,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.fast_rewind,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 25,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    child: IconButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      splashRadius: 20,
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.play_arrow,
                        size: 35,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    splashRadius: 20,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.fast_forward,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    splashRadius: 20,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.stop_circle,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Spacer(),
                  IconButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      splashRadius: 20,
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.share_outlined,
                          color: Colors.white)),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      splashRadius: 20,
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.grey))
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the code for the miniplayer which should pop up when after a songtile is pressed and the song screen is minimized

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Mini_Player extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 70,
      child: Card(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          elevation: 10,
          color: Colors.black54,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 66,
                height: 66,
                child: Image.asset('assets/rockstar.jpg'),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Title',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Artist',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              new Spacer(),
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 25,
                backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                child: IconButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  splashRadius: 20,
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.play_arrow,
                    size: 35,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              )
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

I am really bad with stateful widgets and setstate so please help me

This is the homescreen on which the miniplayer and songtile etc are rendered

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topRight,
          end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          colors: [
            Color.fromARGB(1, 158, 156, 156),
            Colors.black,
          ],
        )),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SafeArea(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    greeting(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 35,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                  new Spacer(),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.settings,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Search_Screen(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Text(
                    'Recommended',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Spacer(),
              ],
            ),
            SongREC(),
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Text(
                    'Jump back in',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Spacer(),
              ],
            ),
            SongJBI(),
            new Spacer(),
            Mini_Player(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            label: 'Search',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.library_add,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            label: 'My Library',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should look into [MiniPlayer](https://pub.dev/packages/miniplayer) package.